# find $inf_C \int_0^1 |f'(x) - f(x)|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity, contest-math

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the reals and $C$ the set of all functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with a continuous derivative and satisfying $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1.$ Find $\inf_C \int_0^1 |f'(x)-f(x)|dx$.

In the solution below, I was wondering how to formally justify why we can take $f(x)$ to be an arbitrary monotonic increasing function with the required values at $0$ and $\epsilon$ and with the required derivative at $\epsilon$? I was thinking of replacing $kx$ by a quadratic for some $y\leq x\leq \epsilon$ but then I'd need to make sure that the linear function passing through the origin has the same derivative as the quadratic at $y$ and the same value at $y$, which isn't always possible. Alternatively, I might need to evaluate the integral of something like $\int_0^{\epsilon} |ax^2 +bx + c|dx$ for suitably chosen constants $a,b,c$, which seems more complicated than it needs to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the quadratic over the whole of $[0,\varepsilon]$. If $f(x) = ax^2 + bx$, you only need the two conditions $$ a\varepsilon^2 + b\varepsilon = e^{\varepsilon - 1}, \\ 2a\varepsilon + b = e^{\varepsilon -1} \\ \iff a = -\varepsilon^{-2} (1-\varepsilon) e^{\varepsilon - 1} , b = \varepsilon^{-1}(2-\varepsilon)e^{\varepsilon - 1}.$$

Now observe that $$ \int_0^\varepsilon |f(x)| \le |a|\varepsilon^3/3 + b\varepsilon^2/2 = O(\varepsilon).$$ Further, we have that $2ax + b > 0$ for $x < \varepsilon,$ and so $$\int_0^\varepsilon |f'| = \int_0^\varepsilon f' = e^{\varepsilon -1}.$$

---

Aside: In general, if you need to smoothly stitch two functions over an interval, then you have four conditions (the values and derivatives at the end points should match). To give yourself enough wiggle room, you need at least four parameters to play with - i.e., you should use a cubic $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. In the above, we actually had only three conditions - setting $f(0) = 0$, and matching the value and derivative at $\varepsilon,$ and so a quadratic (which has $3$ parameters) sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution establishes in the middle line that any function gives you at least $1/e$. This shows that the infimum is at least $1/e$. (This should be the first line of the solution really.)

Now you want to show that the infimum is at most $1/e$. The first paragraph and the third paragraph show this. To get an upper bound on an infimum, you can choose which functions to put in, so there's no 'justification' needed, they just select a function that gets a result of at most $1/e + \delta$ for small $\delta$.